# The sum of ten distinct natural numbers is $62$. Show that their product is a multiple of $1440$.

Tags: elementary-number-theory

> The sum of ten distinct natural numbers is $62$. Show that their product is a multiple of $1440$.

I know how to prove that it is a multiple of $60$
Lets write: $a_1+a_2+...+a_{10}=62$. Assuming $a_1<a_2<\cdots <a_{10}$ we search the maximal value of $a_{10}$. This is the difference of $62$ and the minimal value the sum  $a_1+a_2+\cdots+a_9$ can take. As this value is given by $1+2+\cdots+9=45$, it follows that $a_{10}=62-45=17$. That means that for any $a_i>17$, there are no $9$ natural numbers to satisfy our initial sum.

So a solution would be $1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,17$.

If $a_{10}=16$, the unique solution is $a_9=10$, the smaller solutions being unchanged as to preserve the distinctness.

If $a_{10}=15$, then $a_9=11$ or $a_8=10$.

If $a_{10}=14$, then $a_9=12$ or $a_8=11$ or $a_7=10$.

If $a_{10}=13$, then $a_8=12$ or $a_7=11$ or $a_6=10$.

If $a_{10}=12$, $a_9=13$ or $a_6=11$ or $a_5=10$. And from here on, the situation repeats.

We observe that the numbers $3,4,5$ or $6,10$ or $5,12$ repeat and as their products are $60$, then $60$ divides the product of $a_1,\cdots,a_{10}$. I don't know how to expand for $1440$. Any help, please?

Comment: the sum of $10$ distinct positive integers?

Comment: @Jorge Yes, sum of $10$ natural numbers

Comment: Anatol, it is vitally important that the numbers are distinct, and you should state this in your question: "The sum of ten distinct positive integers" etc.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Consider potential minimal counter-examples which might not be multiples of the prime factorisation of $1440=2^53^25$ and show that the sums cannot be $62$:

You must have a multiple of $5$ in the product since $1+2+3+4+6+7+8+9+11+12=63$ is too big and any smaller sum must have a multiple of $5$.

You must have a multiple of $9$ in the product since $1+2+3+4+5+7+8+10+11+13=64$ is too big and any smaller sum must have a second multiple of $3$.

You also want to show you must have a multiple of $32=2^5$ in the product, but that is a little more complicated.  There must be an even number of odd numbers to get an even sum, and since there are $10$ numbers you must have an even number of even numbers.

- If you have six or more even numbers, then you will have at least $2^6=64$ in the product
- If you have four even numbers then at least one of them must be a multiple of $4$ so giving $32$ in the product, since $1+2+3+5+6+7+9+10+11+14=68$ is too big
- If you have two or fewer even numbers then the sum will be too big, since $1+2+3+4+5+7+9+11+13+15=70$ is too big

So you must have $5 \times 9 \times 32=1440$ in the product.

You have given an example of $17 \times 9!= 6168960=1440 \times 4284$ and this is in fact the smallest example.

Comment: Thank you! It is a good, elegant answer.

Answer (score 0):

Experimental approach:

Sum of first 11 numbers is:

$S=\frac {11}2(11+1)=66$

$66-62=4$

So we delete 4 and our numbers are:

$1, 2, 3, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11$

which their product is a multiple of 1440.

Comment: Well yes, but it is not unique as you can remove two numbers and add one, greater than 11.

Comment: $1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,17$ is another of the $15$ possibilities (they correspond to the partitions of $7=62-55$)